# How to get data from textbox that is in another window

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a main window and when users click a button i create a new window to ask informations.
But after how i get these informations in my main window????

```
//This is the button event handler in main window


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        AddServer window = new AddServer();
        window.Show();

}
```

thank you

Comment: I don't have time to put together an example, but I usually either put a callback method into the main window for the child to call at some specific point or create an event for the main window to handle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send data from an opened window back to its opener in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708830/how-to-send-data-from-an-opened-window-back-to-its-opener-in-wpf)